# How to use non-static node variables in puppet?

Tags: puppet

In puppet, I'd like to set a variable on a node (let's say {'acts_as_balancer' => 0}, and then run a script to change that variable to some other (now say {'acts_as_balancer' => 1}). So far I've seen only variables being used as constants in Puppet. What is the way to set variables as non-constants, on nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Variables are (supposed to be) immutable, so you need to do something else, and it really depends on what you are actually trying to achieve.

If you want to run a script that will change the variables on the puppetmaster, then you can just use Hiera and have the script write the proper YAML files. You can also use the [generate](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#generate) command, but you will have to be really careful with this.

But you make it sound like you would like to do it during catalog compilation. This is a bad idea at best, as you will almost certainly have to rely on a solution that is parse order dependent.